# $v_{2}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2k-1})=2v_{2}(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The Problem: $v_{2}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2k-1})=2v_{2}(n)$,$v_{2}(n)$is the 2-adic valuation of n.
I can solve this problem in the case of $n=2^{m}$,
but I want to know how to solve this problem for all positive integer n

Comment: What is the 2-adic valuation for a fraction?

Comment: 2-adic valuation for fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ is $v_{2}(p)-v_{2}(q)$